# How to merge multiple contacts of same person?

Tags: contacts

An Android newbie here --- I've recently got my first Android phone (HTC Desire S) and I'm trying to clean up a mess of my contacts from a SIM card (three of them, in fact). For example, a certain Edward Bloggs might have several entries:

- Edward Bloggs @london, mob
- Eddie B @london, home [it's his nickname, we all call him Eddie B]
- Eddie @hawaii [he's got a vacation home in there, and... er... who likes paying roaming charges anyway]

All these are in the 'first name' field or split randomly by the phone into the first, middle, and last names.

- There are, of course, Google entries from me sending emails to both his work and personal emails.

Now, the question is --- is there a way to merge these contacts? Preferably something where one could select which ones to merge. Anything short of exporting all contacts onto a PC and manually editing the VCF files would be great.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do is open the Contacts application, press the menu button, and go to "Import/Export". From there, you import from your SIM card and import them to your Google account. Once you have imported all the contacts, open the [Google Contacts manager](https://www.google.com/contacts_v2/u/0/#contacts) and click on "More", then select "Find & Merge Duplicates".

[image]

You may have to go through and edit some manually if they have really different names. But then you can merge again if needed.

Comment: Thanks! Nevertheless, is there a standalone tool? A separate question is if there is any sort of heuristics: the HTC Contacts application does not seem to recognize E.S.Bloggs@domain.com and e.s.bloggs@domain.com to be a prime candidate for merging.